# Pass asp.net controls as params to javascript function

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am trying to get a javascript function to work properly with my asp.net controls.  I have two radio buttons and three textboxes.

When the first radio button is clicked I would like to disable the third textbox and when the second radio button is clicked I would like to disable the third text box. See the attachment for a screenshot.

I have tested that the function works by adding "OnClick" to the first radio button and setting AN ALERT WHICH IS WORKING.

However, I am not sure how to pass the controls in to the function to have access to them.  Anyone know how to do this?

**Screenshot**
[image]

**ASP.NET**

```
<asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton1" runat="server" Checked="True" GroupName="DateTimeQuery" OnClick="TimeRangeClickEvent()"/>
<asp:TextBox ID="startdatetext" Enabled="true" runat="server" MaxLength="10"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="enddatetext" Enabled="true" runat="server" MaxLength="10"></asp:TextBox>

<asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton2" runat="server" GroupName="DateTimeQuery" OnClick="TimeRangeClickEvent() />
<asp:TextBox ID="withinthepast" Enabled="true" runat="server" Text="1"></asp:TextBox>
```

**Javascript**

```
<script>
        function TimeRangeClickEvent(How do I pass asp.net controls here)
        {
            alert('Working');            
        }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `ClientID` control properties to get IDs of HTML elements and then work with them from Javascript. [More info.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientid(v=vs.110).aspx)

In Javascript:

```
var radio1 = document.getElementById('<%=RadioButton1.ClientID%>');
```

When you have all your HTML elements you just need to handle necessary change/clicked/selected events in javascript to make it work.

Comment: Yep this will work.  The only thing I had to add different as .checked at the end of the getElementByID to pass in the value whether the radio button was checked or not like this: var radio1 = document.getElementById('<%=RadioButton1.ClientID%>').checked; Thanks